# Resize element width on window resize jquery

Tags: jquery, window-resize, onresize

I am computing elements width on page load with jq and works fine , trying to automate on window resize but kinda does not work. Desired effect: Boxes should auto resize on window resize and not drop down.

http://jsfiddle.net/yMcXm/4/

any help is appreciated . Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `$(window).resize` See below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cw = $('#container').width();
    $(".box").width(cw / 5);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var cw = $('#container').width();
        $(".box").width(cw / 5);
    });
});
```

Also used overflow property on the `container` and `box_in`, so that the elements/text inside are contained/hidden.. instead of going out.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/skram/yMcXm/7/

Comment: sure did. I did not pay attention.