# How to Dynamically Update outerHeight of An Element When Another Element Changes in Height on Window Resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bit of a jquery / javascript noob question here. I have a subnav element that I am sticking to the bottom of my primary nav once someone hits a certain scroll point. To do that, I'm offsetting the subnav element by the height of the main nav element, as shown below.

```
$(function() {      
  $('.sticky-nav').stickybits({
    useStickyClasses: true,
    stickyBitStickyOffset: $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight(),
  });
});
```

The problem that I'm running into is '.navbar-fixed-top' has a different height at mobile / tablet and desktop sizes (the height changes at 992px) and the offset gets messed up if someone resizes the screen (i.e., if they start at desktop, and then resize to mobile / tablet, there's too much space above the subnav because the main nav was taller in desktop).

My question is, how can I update the code above to dynamically update the outerHeight when the height of the .navbar-fixed-top element changes?

I tried the code below, inspired by the answer to this question: [Resize element width on window resize jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984185/resize-element-width-on-window-resize-jquery), but it's not working

```
$(function() {
  var topNavHeight =  $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight();
  $(window).on('resize', function(event) {
    var topNavHeight = $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight();
  });   
  $('.sticky-nav').stickybits({
    useStickyClasses: true,
    stickyBitStickyOffset: topNavHeight,
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't you have to destroy then re-initialise the sticky plugin with the new height?  Also including the var inside your resize means you are declaring a new local var and not updating the global var

Comment: @Pete - I think you're right and looks like halcyon took a similar approach below. Also, I wanted to acknowledge and thank you for changing the language of the original comment. You removed a "you realize..." to make it more of a teaching comment. As a jquery / javascript noob, the local variable issue was something I did not realize and I appreciate you pointing that out in a way that was instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
$(function() {
    let stickything;

    function set_sticky() {
        if (stickything) {
            stickything.cleanup();
        }
        stickything = $('.sticky-nav').stickybits({
            useStickyClasses: true,
            stickyBitStickyOffset: $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight(),
        });
    }

    $(window).on('resize', set_sticky);
    set_sticky();
});
```

Just changing a variable isn't enough, you have to tell stickbits to update. There doesn't seem be a way to update the offset so this just reinitializes it.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you!

Also, appreciate the additional context / explanation below the code. Helped me to learn / understand what's going on here.